# how to use vh units instead of pixels for .scrolltop functions

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a menu bar who's class I want to change after a users scrolls to the next div, the div is 100vh tall. The function below works only with screens my size, anything smaller or bigger the animation will go to early or too late.

How do I make the units that this function uses vh? Thanks

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll >= 600) {   <---- change to vh units not px-----
    $(".home").removeClass("open");
}
```

Comment: You can't; you have to work out how many pixels `100vh` is and then use that pixel-value in the `if` condition.

Comment: @David Thomas : how can we calculate the pixels when the 100vh is different in pixel on the different screen sizes ? that is why we use 100vh, because we want a div, section or whatever element to have the same size like the screen of the visitor... any other idea ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

100vh is the actual view height of that screen.
so when you use different size screens 100vh will be calculated to a different size.

Comment: I know and i guess Anfa A knows it as well and so, we are looking for the answer for how to use vh units in the script however screen size is... i want my header be resized when the first section is passed by scroll and as my first section height is 100vh, i do not see how can i do the resize in a different way.

Answer (score 5):

Use `window.innerHeight` and multiply it by fraction. For example, if you want 60 vh use `(window.innerHeight)*0.6`.

I'm not familliar with jQuery, but with vanillaJS it would be

```
if (window.pageYOffset > window.innerHeight)
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming across this.
What I did for this was simply create a variable that gets the height of the viewport (which will return a value in pixels) and then use that variable in the function.

My script would scroll down 1vh

```
var scrollBtn = $('#scrolldown');
var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // value in pixels
scrollBtn.click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + windowHeight
  },2000);
});
```

For this question the solution would be something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= windowHeight) {
    $(".home").removeClass("open");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an invisible fixed element at the height you want the lower div to reach before changing the menu class. Position this fixed element using vh and for your scroll function test if the lower div has crossed the fixed element.

CSS:

```
#fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10vh;         /*or whatever height you want*/
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   

    var test = $('#fixed').offset().top;
    var lowerDivPosition = $('#lowerDiv').offset().top;

    if (lowerDivPosition >= test) { 
        $(".home").removeClass("open");
    };
});
```