# Is there a way to window.scrollY using vh?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Is there any way to use `vh` in `window.scrollY`? Or is there an alternative to `window.scrollY` that enables the use of `vh`?

I have a hero image that occupies `90vh` of the screen. I want the navbar to change colors from `transparent` to `#f0f0f0` after scrolling 90vh. See line 7 for the `window.scrollY`.

Thank you.

```
function Header() {
  const [navBackground, setNavBackground] = useState(false);
  const navRef = useRef();
  navRef.current = navBackground;
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const show = window.scrollY > [insert 90vh here];
      if (navRef.current !== show) {
        setNavBackground(show);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="header__header">
      <div className="header__navbar-container">
        <Navbar
          className="header__navbar"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: navBackground ? "#f0f0f0" : "transparent",
          }}
        >
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `window.pageYOffset > (window.innerHeight)*0.9`.

This is the reference I used:
[how to use vh units instead of pixels for .scrolltop functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006979/how-to-use-vh-units-instead-of-pixels-for-scrolltop-functions)